# How to create border between two divs with dynamically changing heights?

Tags: css

I have two divs, and their height is changing dynamically. The left div might be taller than the right one, and opposite is also possible. How to create a border between them that can change dynamically according to their height? The border should be from the top to the bottom of the row. I am using Bootstrap 4, and I prefer to be only CSS.

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left col-md-6">a</div>
        <div class="right col-md-6">asdasdasd
            <br/>a
            <br/>asdsad
            <br/>asd
            <br/>asd
            <br/>asdsa
            <br/>d
            <br/>as
            <br/>d
            <br/>asdsad
            <br/>asdasdasd
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left col-md-6">
              <br/>a
            <br/>asdsad
            <br/>asd
            <br/>asd
            <br/>asdsa
            <br/>d
            <br/>as
            <br/>d
            <br/>asdsad
            <br/>asdasdasd
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="right col-md-6">
           asdasd
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ravepgz6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply give both containers a border and give the right div a `margin-left: -1px;`.

```
.left {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.right {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ravepgz6/1/

This will, however, fail if you have a percentage-based gap between the divs (as might result from using Bootstrap columns). For that use case, please describe or even better, show an image of what the result should look like.

Comment: Nice solution! You might want to add your code (or at least what you added) to your answer.

Comment: I had a similar solution that skips the negative margin.  https://jsfiddle.net/91wv8ckm/.  But it's the same in principle.

Comment: You are using the pseudo element `:after` rather than putting borders on the element itself. This works as long as these elements are not already being used. It would, however, be my preferred way as well if I had to implement a solution that works with the aforementioned column gaps.